# SwiftUI .onDrop getting error “Cannot load representation of type public.data”

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-ondrop

Hi
I am trying to implement Drag and Drop with custom Type in SwiftUI. For test purposes I have two tiles that I want to drag onto each other. My Class is defined as follows and conforms to both NSItemProviderReading, NSItemProviderWriting.

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

final class Tile: NSObject, Identifiable, ObservableObject, Codable, NSItemProviderReading, NSItemProviderWriting{
    
    public enum Issues: Error {
        case invalidTypeIdentifier
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case title
    }
    
    var id:UUID = UUID()
    @Published var title:String
    
    static let myTypeUTI: String = UTType.data.identifier
    static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String]{
        return [myTypeUTI]
    }
    
    static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> Self {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let decoded = try? decoder.decode(Tile.self, from: data)
        return decoded as! Self
    }
    
    static var writableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String]{
        return [myTypeUTI]
    }
    
    func loadData(withTypeIdentifier typeIdentifier: String, forItemProviderCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping @Sendable (Data?, Error?) -> Void) -> Progress? {
        let progress = Progress(totalUnitCount: 100)
        guard typeIdentifier == Self.myTypeUTI else {
            completionHandler(nil, nil)
            return progress
        }
        do {
            let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
            let data = try jsonEncoder.encode(self)
            completionHandler(data, Issues.invalidTypeIdentifier )
            /// <-call from onDrop adds valid data to completionHandler->
        }
        catch { completionHandler(nil, error) }
        return progress
    }
    
    //: ===================================================================================== ://
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
    
    //: ===================================================================================== ://
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title )
    }
    
    //: ===================================================================================== ://
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.title, forKey: .title)
    }
    
}
```

And the code of the TileView is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

    struct TileView: View {
        @ObservedObject var tile:Tile
        var body: some View {
            Text(tile.title)
                .padding(30)
                .background(.yellow)
                .onDrag {
                    return NSItemProvider(object: tile )
                }
                .onDrop(of: [Tile.myTypeUTI], isTargeted:nil ) { providers in
                    if let firstItem = providers.first{
                        let value = firstItem.loadObject(ofClass: Tile.self ) { tileItem, error in
                            /// <-calls back to Tile.loadData and in the call if appears that it prepares valid data ->
                            if let error{
                                print( error )
                            }
                            else{
                                print( "complete drop")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return true
                }
        }
    }
```

However when one tile is dragged onto the other I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load representation of type public.data" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.data, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003e235a0 {Error Domain=SimpleDragAndDrop.Tile.Issues Code=0 "(null)"}}
```

When I set a break in Tile.LoadData it seems to process the completionHandler as expected with valid data and no errors, however if the view the Data is not passed back and the error is generated. 
Thanks for you help in advance.